# Is it possible to highlight text as the user types?

Tags: python, user-interface, text, pyqt

I'm trying to create an input box that highlights text as the user writes it.

```
patients = ["AB", "GH", "JS", "LP"]
attributes = ["medication", "weight", "mobility"]
commands = ["get" , "add", "replace", "delete"]
```

I'd like it to format each type of word differently e.g.

AB add medication aspirin' -> '**AB** *add* MEDICATION "aspirin"'

JS get medication -> **JS** *get* MEDICATION

Is this possible? I'm not necessirilly looking for the code which would pull it off; I'd just like to know if it's doable before I commit serious time to working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but only for input widgets based on QTextDocument, such as QPlainTextEdit or QTextEdit, as the basic one-line widget QLineEdit doesn't support formatting.

You need to create a subclass of [QSyntaxHighlighter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsyntaxhighlighter.html) and override its [`highlightBlock()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsyntaxhighlighter.html#highlightBlock) function, then cycle through all groups, create a valid regex and provide the relative format:

```
def highlightBlock(self, text):
    fmt = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
    fmt.setFontWeight(QtGui.QFont.Bold)
    patientList = '|'.join('({})'.format(v) for v in patients)
    patientRegEx = QtCore.QRegularExpression(
        r'\b({})\b'.format(patientList)
        )
    rxIter = QtCore.QRegularExpressionMatchIterator(
        patientRegEx.globalMatch(text))
    while rxIter.hasNext():
        match = rxIter.next()
        self.setFormat(
            match.capturedStart(), 
            match.capturedLength(), 
            fmt)
```

Then set the highlighter on the document for the text edit:

```
    self.inputField = QTextEdit()
    self.highlighter = MySyntaxHighlighter(self.inputField.document())
```

Note that it seems that there's a known and unresolved [bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-32619) in the syntax highlighter, so setting the font capitalization will *not* work.

Unfortunately there's no easy workaround for this, so you need to find other ways to highlight the attributes.

To know the options available for character formats, see the documentation for [QTextCharFormat](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcharformat.html) and also [QTextFormat](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextformat.html) (from which it inherits), which also provides useful functions like `setBackground` and `setForeground`.

Comment: I'm having some trouble getting this to work; if you tested this using a script and still have it handy, could you please post it?

Comment: @JohnSalter see the update. If you still have more trouble, explain *what* trouble you have.

Comment: @JohnSalter 1. I cannot know how you do the imports, if you import a submodule instead of indivudual classes, then you have to use `submodule.class()`, so it's `QtWidgets.QTextEdit()`; 2. you explicitly wanted to know **only** if it could be done, I've already exceeded your question by providing the basic code, sorry to be rude, but this is not a tutorial website; 3. have you created a subclass of `QSyntaxHighlighter` as explained in my answer? `highlightBlock` must be implemented in that subclass, and you shall not call it, since it's an overridden method that will be called by Qt`;

Comment: Finally, files generated by pyuic should never, ***ever*** be manually modified; it's a bad practice that almost always leads to errors and unexpected behavior, because those files are only intended to be used as imported modules in your main script(s) which is what actually contains the logic implementation of your program. If you want to use UI files, then please follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: Apologies, I misread your original answer and realised just after publishing my comment. I've accepted answer.